# Ubuntu 14.04 Blank Desktop

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation

This is my first time with Ubuntu (or any Linux distro for that matter).  I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7. The initial install went flawlessly without any errors. After the install, I was able to login with the user I created, and then it booted up to a blank purplish screen. The only thing showing is my cursor. Left or right clicking doesn't bring up any options. I left it for an hour thinking it is still installing. Still has the blank screen. I reloaded the DVD thinking I will get a 'repair' option, but only get 'Try Ubuntu' and 'install Ubuntu'. This is on a dell laptop. Can anyone please give me a detailed step by step fix? My first experience with Ubuntu isn't going too well.

Comment: is that 64 bit or 32 bit architecture?
or maybe try to checksum your iso, i think it's corrupt or something similar

Answer (score 0):

When in the blank screen press the following keys Ctrl Alt F1 or F2, if everything went well you should see the terminal screen (similar to the windows command screen). The text; Ubuntu 14.04 LTS *your computer name* tty1 or tty2 should appear on screen.

The following line will be; *your computer name* login: _. You can login using your user name and password. You should then see the text user name@computer name:~$.

Type ls -a and press enter.The output should be a listing of folders and files. If you are able to complete the steps your system should basically work. It's probably the GUI which is not functioning properly.

You can try installing the desktop by the following command sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop (this worked for older versions). Follow the on screen prompts. If it works for you, login to the GUI with Ctrl Alt F7 or F8. If you see the desktop you should be okay, if not we need to look at different options.

Comment: When I press control alt f1, the screen goes black and an error message pops up "[. 204.226322] nouveau E [ DRM] GPU lockup- switching to fbcon". I didn't see the Ubuntu version or my PC name. There's a blinking cursor at the bottom of the error message. Should I proceed with your suggestion ?